# Sqlalchemy insert column data based on values in other columns/tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a project that parses json data and inserts it to tables. The data comes from multiple sources and the constants, as you can see in the screenshot, are "game_ref" and "game_datetime". My goal is to be able to take the "event_id" in the MLB table and insert it to the MGM table based on the "game_datetime" and "game_ref" values in each table. Can anyone point me toward which sqlalchemy method (core or ORM) would be best to accomplish this task?

[image]

```
Base = declarative_base()

class GamelistMLB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mlb_gamelist'
    
    event_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    game_ref = Column(String)
    game_datetime = Column(Integer)

    mgm_id = relationship("GamelistMGM", backref="mlb_gamelist")

    
class GamelistMGM(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mgm_gamelist'
    
    book_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    game_ref = Column(String)
    game_datetime = Column(Integer)
    event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('mlb_gamelist.event_id'))


def create_tables(engine):
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables supposed to be - 1 to 1, 1 to many, many to 1?  Are instances of the two entities created separately or is it possible to create both (and assign `event_id`) at the same time?

Comment: What does your input `json` look like? does it contain content for both tables already? Or are the tables you show the starting point for the *linking job*?

Comment: Each table comes from a different json source url. As of right now I have each json structure thrown into a list and then parse the data (starting with gamelist) for each source. I think that answers both of your questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have data in the database, the below should work for you.
*If, however, you can plug in the solution at the data load phase, it might be best to do the linking immediately on load.*

Basically, what you would like to achieve in `SQL` terms is the following:

```sql
-- update the column `event_id` on MGM from MLB
UPDATE  mgm_gamelist
SET     event_id = mlb_gamelist.event_id

FROM    mlb_gamelist
WHERE   
        mgm_gamelist.event_id IS NULL -- unless it is already set

    -- where the data row matches that of MLB
    AND mgm_gamelist.game_ref = mlb_gamelist.game_ref
    AND mgm_gamelist.game_datetime = mlb_gamelist.game_datetime
```

The same implementation in python:

```py
# assign aliases to the `Table` underlying mapped classes to shorten the expression
tMGM = GamelistMGM.__table__
tMLB = GamelistMLB.__table__

statement = (
    tMGM.update()
    .where(tMGM.c.event_id.is_(None))
    .where(tMGM.c.game_ref == tMLB.c.game_ref)
    .where(tMGM.c.game_datetime == tMLB.c.game_datetime)
    .values(event_id=tMLB.c.event_id)
)
res = session.execute(statement)
print(res.rowcount)
```

*Now, this "UPDATE FROM" might not work with all RDBMS but it does with Postgres.*

---

**Edit-1:**
The case of immediately linking during the load phase is showing below:

```py
for _sample_json_row in _sample_json_input:
    mgm = GamelistMGM(**_sample_json_row)

    # try to find MLB to link to
    mlb = (
        session.query(GamelistMLB)
        .filter(GamelistMLB.game_ref == mgm.game_ref)
        .filter(GamelistMLB.game_datetime == mgm.game_datetime)
        .first()
    )
    if mlb:
        # this will update the `event_id` automatically
        mgm.mgm_id = mlb  # NOTE: you should rename `mgm_id` to just `mlb` or `rel_mlb`

    session.add(mgm)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm still trying to wrap my head around sql/sqlalchemy so could you further explain what you mean by linking immediately on load? If I understand you correctly I should be able to do it. The data for MLB gamelist is loaded into a table first from it's respective json and MGM gamelist, etc (there are 4 more sources) get loaded after. Does that make sense?

Comment: I ask this because I'm going to encounter more situations where I need to perform similar operations. Most of what I'm doing is just making sure the data from each source is properly "connected" so to speak. All of my experience is in pandas where I would just load the tables and execute `mgm.merge(mlb['event_id', 'game_ref', 'game_datetime'], on=['game_ref', 'game_datetime'], how='left')`

Comment: You answered my question already in your comment. I think that my solution should work. Whenever you load your `json` for the `MGM` table, you might want to run it.

Alternative would be to try to find the proper MLB record while you are creating those for MGM, but if they are not in the database (yet), you will still have to try linking later.

Comment: How to you convert json to the database? With `pandas.to_sql(..)`?

Comment: I thought it might be best to leave out the pandas aspect so when I was using core the code was `insert(self.table).values(site_data)`. Now that I'm switching to ORM my first attempt is using bulk_insert_mappings. Not sure if that's the best approach though.

Comment: I finally got far enough to give your method a try and it worked perfect. Thanks a ton. Do you think it would be better to insert entries 1 by 1 instead of in bulk? I'd like to be able to refresh the table every hour or so and get the latest data from the jsons and I'm not sure how that would interact with bulk inserts unless maybe setting a timestamp as pk would work?

Comment: (assuming i understand your use case well) I would probably do the following: a) i would run my bulk linking `UPDATE` scheduled on a regular basis, b) if it is possible that MGM loaded into the table before the corresponding MLB is, i would also run after each new loading of MLB; c) run it also when MGMs are loaded in the database, and it is only this case [and potentially b)] where it would make sense to insert data 1 by 1 with trying to find it first... I will add sample code to the answer.

Comment: That all makes perfect sense. Thanks again!